# How to increase the speed of certain turtles (Netlogo)?

Tags: model, netlogo

I created a model that represents 2 bus stops. At the moment the turtles board the bus and then the bus will drive away. However, I want the boarding speed of the turtles to be different. In other words, I want that the turtles at the upper station move faster than the lower one (or the bottom ones slower than the top ones). I don't know how to do this... Do you guys have any tips? My code is below. Thanks in advance!
Code:

```
turtles-own [speed]
breed [busses bus]
globals [time] 

to setup

clear-all
  
  ;; above
  ask patches with [pxcor = 2 and pycor = 5][set pcolor white]
  ask patches with [pxcor = 2 and pycor = 4][set pcolor white]
  ask patches with [pxcor = 0 and pycor = 4][set pcolor white]
  ask patches with [pxcor = 0 and pycor = 5][set pcolor white]
  ask patches with [pxcor = 1 and pycor = 4][set pcolor white]
  ask patches with [pxcor = 1 and pycor = 5][set pcolor white]
  ask patches with [pxcor = 3 and pycor = 4][set pcolor white]
  ask patches with [pxcor = 3 and pycor = 5][set pcolor white]
  ask patches with [pxcor = 4 and pycor = 4][set pcolor white]
  ask patches with [pxcor = 4 and pycor = 5][set pcolor white]
  ask patches with [pxcor = 5 and pycor = 4][set pcolor white]
  ask patches with [pxcor = 5 and pycor = 5][set pcolor white]
  ask patches with [pycor = 6][
    set pcolor gray
  ]
  
   ;;middle
  ask patches with [pxcor = 2 and pycor = -6][set pcolor white]
  ask patches with [pxcor = 2 and pycor = -5][set pcolor white]
  ask patches with [pxcor = 0 and pycor = -5][set pcolor white]
  ask patches with [pxcor = 0 and pycor = -6][set pcolor white]
  ask patches with [pxcor = 1 and pycor = -5][set pcolor white]
  ask patches with [pxcor = 1 and pycor = -6][set pcolor white]
  ask patches with [pxcor = 3 and pycor = -5][set pcolor white]
  ask patches with [pxcor = 3 and pycor = -6][set pcolor white]
  ask patches with [pxcor = 4 and pycor = -5][set pcolor white]
  ask patches with [pxcor = 4 and pycor = -6][set pcolor white]
  ask patches with [pxcor = 5 and pycor = -5][set pcolor white]
  ask patches with [pxcor = 5 and pycor = -6][set pcolor white]
  ask patches with [pycor = -4][
    set pcolor gray
  ]
  
   ;;below
  ask patches with [pxcor = 2 and pycor = -15][set pcolor white]
  ask patches with [pxcor = 2 and pycor = -14][set pcolor white]
  ask patches with [pxcor = 0 and pycor = -14][set pcolor white]
  ask patches with [pxcor = 0 and pycor = -15][set pcolor white]
  ask patches with [pxcor = 1 and pycor = -14][set pcolor white]
  ask patches with [pxcor = 1 and pycor = -15][set pcolor white]
  ask patches with [pxcor = 3 and pycor = -14][set pcolor white]
  ask patches with [pxcor = 3 and pycor = -15][set pcolor white]
  ask patches with [pxcor = 4 and pycor = -14][set pcolor white]
  ask patches with [pxcor = 4 and pycor = -15][set pcolor white]
  ask patches with [pxcor = 5 and pycor = -14][set pcolor white]
  ask patches with [pxcor = 5 and pycor = -15][set pcolor white]
  ask patches with [pycor = -13][
    set pcolor gray
  ]
    ;; bus above 
    create-busses 1[
    set color red
    set size 7
    set xcor 3
    set ycor 8
    set shape "bus"
    set heading 90
  ]
  
    ;; bus middle
    create-busses 1[
    set color red
    set size 7
    set xcor 3
    set ycor -2
    set shape "bus"
    set heading 90

]

     ;; bus below
  create-busses 1[
    set color red
    set size 7
    set xcor 3
    set ycor -11
    set shape "bus"
    set heading 90
    

] 
  
  ;; passengers above
      create-turtles Nr_Passengers_1[                        ;; slider
      setxy one-of (range 0 6) one-of (range 4 6)                                                                    
      set color grey                                                              
      set size 1       
      set shape "person"
      set heading towards patch 3 7
      set speed random-float 0.6 + 0.1  
  ]
  
    ;; passengers middle
      create-turtles Nr_Passengers_2[                        ;;slider
      setxy one-of (range 0 6) one-of (range -6 -4)                                                           
      set color blue                                                              
      set size 1       
      set shape "person"
      set heading towards patch 3 -3 
      set speed random-float 0.6 + 0.5
      
  ]
  
    ;; passengers below
      create-turtles Nr_Passengers_3[                        ;; slider
      setxy one-of (range 0 6) one-of (range -15 -13)                                                                     
      set color green                                                              
      set size 1       
      set shape "person"
      set heading towards patch 3 -12
      set speed random-float 0.6 + 0.5 
      
  ]
  
  ask patch 8 10 [set plabel "platform 1"]
  ask patch 4 0 [set plabel "platform 2"]
  ask patch 4 -9 [set plabel "platform 3"]
  
 
  reset-ticks
end



to check-in-1
  ;;above 
  ask turtles[ 
    if shape != "bus"[                                  
      if any? neighbors with [pcolor = grey or pcolor = black] and shape != "bus" [ die]
      ask turtles with [patch-here != patch 3 -12] [fd speed]
        ]
  ]
  
  tick
end



to drive
  
  let SC_3 count turtles with [pycor >= -15 and pycor <= -10 and shape = "people"] 
  if SC_3 <= 0 [
    ask turtles with [pycor = -11 and shape = "bus"][
    forward 33
  ]]
      ask patch 10 -10 [
    set plabel "20 seconds"]

  
  let SC_2 count turtles with [pycor >= -6 and pycor <= -1 and shape = "people"]
  if SC_2 <= 0[
    ask turtles with [pycor = -2 and shape = "bus"][
    forward 33
  ]]
    
  
  let SC_1 count turtles with [pycor >= 4 and pycor <= 8 and shape = "people"] 
  if SC_1 <= 0 [
    ask turtles with [pycor = 8 and shape = "bus"][
     forward 33
  ]
    stop]
  
  
   
  
end



to go
  check-in-1
  drive
  tick 
end
```

Comment: To have a difference in speed, you first need a concept of speed. You use `move-to`, which immediately "teleports" the turtle from their current position to their destination. You would need to let them take a series of small steps

Comment: @LeirsW thankss for your tip!! I tried to do  that at first, but I couldn't get it working... Any suggestions on how to do this?

Comment: @LeirsW if I try it with setting the bus as a target, the turtles will move random trough the world, what is not supposed to happen

Comment: You can use `face` to turn towards the bus where you want them to go. You can give them a turtles-own parameter called `speed` and let them walk speed forward at every step, arriving if their distrance from the bus is less than their speed value

Answer (score 1):

This is an example where I give each turtle their own speed variable between 0 and 0.5, and let them all walk towards the green patch in the middle at their own speed.

In `go-1`, this happens within a single `tick`. I use a `while` loop that continues until all turtles have arrived. One important thing to remember with a `while` loop like this, is that you need to make sure that the condition will eventually be fulfilled. Otherwise your program gets stuck in an endless loop (if that happens, go to the code tab and just make a single change. Doing that exits any loop currently going on). It is advisable to add a second condition for ending the while, such as a counter that goes up with every iteration and if it exceeds a value (for example 10000), the while stops regardless of whether or not the other condition has been met. I use the `error` command here but you could also use `stop`, or include it as a second condition for `while` to run.

As you can see, `while` is useful but requires a bit of extra thought. `go-2` instead ties everything to ticks, and is run with a forever-button on the interface. I suggest using this construction but if you need your passengers to board before the first tick, you'll have to use something like my `go-1`

```
turtles-own [speed]

to setup
  ca
  ask patch 0 0 [set pcolor green]
  crt 5 [
    setxy random-xcor random-ycor 
    set heading towards patch 0 0
    set speed random-float 0.4 + 0.1 ;Sets speed between 0.1 and 0.5
  ]
  
  reset-ticks
  
end

to go-1 ;In this one, the entire walk happens within a single tick
  
  let emergency-stop 0
  while [any? turtles with [patch-here != patch 0 0]] [
    ask turtles with [patch-here != patch 0 0] [fd speed]
    set emergency-stop emergency-stop + 1
    display
    if emergency-stop > 10000 [error "emergency stop exited the while loop"]
  ]
  
  tick
  
end


to go-2 ;In this one, the walk happens over multiple ticks

  if not any? turtles with [patch-here != patch 0 0] [stop]
  
  ask turtles with [patch-here != patch 0 0] [fd speed]
  
  tick

end
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I have improved my code a lot already (see above). However, I still have 1 problem left. A bus will only leave when all passengers of all platforms are boarded. However, If all the passengers from the lowest platform are checked in, I want that bus to leave, while the other platforms might not be empty yet. I tried to do this by using the 'count' command (see code). But this doesn't seem to work. Do you have any suggestions how to make this work?

Comment: @DwayneJohnson This is where your usage of `neighbors` comes back and bites you in the *ss. You ask all passengers with a grey or black neighbor to die, before letting them move. Given that they are standing on a 2x6 white platform with black and grey all around, every single one of them has a black or grey neighbor and will die immediately, without moving. Please just change to using `patch-here` for that condition.

Comment: Or even better, there is a primitive <breeds>-here, so you can use: `if any? busses-here [die]`

Comment: Second comment: you call `tick` in `check-in-1` and once more in `go`. This is definitely bad modelling practice since it means that every time you call `go`, you will tick twice instead of once.

Comment: Third comment: you count turtles with the shape `"people"`. This will always be 0 since there is no shape `"people"`. If you look into your setup, all your passengers have the shape `"person"`

Comment: Fourth comment: `ask turtles with [patch-here != patch 3 -12]` This piece of code only contains the destination for your bottom set of passengers.

Comment: Fifth comment: in `check-in-1` you have a construction that even experienced coders fall prey to but that should absolutely be avoided. You `ask turtles [ ask turtles [...]]`. So each turtle commands each turtle to do something. This means that every turtle will complete the thing asked of them not once, but once for each turtle. So if you have 10 turtles, each turtle will complete the same task 10 times.

Comment: Sixth comment: To be taken together with comment 1: Your turtles currently don't walk towards the bus but towards the patch just south of the bus. Either let them walk towards the bus and use `if any? busses-here []`, or let them walk towards the patch directly south of the bus and use `if any? busses-on patch-at 0 1 [die]`. `patch-at 0 1` refers to the patch directly north of the caller.

Comment: Or even `if any? busses-on neighbors`, if you want to stick with neighbors

Comment: Lastly: I suggest you first try to get 1 bus working perfectly instead of struggling with 3 busses at the same time right now

Comment: I'll throw you a little bone: `ask humans [ ifelse any? busses-on patch-at 0 1 [die] [fd speed]]` This is currently my entire `check-in-1` procedure. (I did make humans into a breed, that works a lot easier than what you are doing with shapes)